# React <input type='text' не вводятся данные если устанавливаю value={searchData}

Tags: reactjs

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема ? Есть обычный input type='text' который нужно инициализировать значением из state. Но как только я это делаю, - символы в поле не вводятся ?!

```
const inputSearchData = useRef(null);
const { searchData } = state;

  console.log('searchData = ', typeof searchData, '(', searchData, ')')     // searchData =  string (  )
  // searchData = '' 

  return (
          <input 
            // value={searchData}  <--- Если эту строку раскомментировать символы не вводятся
            ref={inputSearchData}            
            type='text'
            className='input-text'
            id='sExpression'
            onChange={changeFilter}  // при этом Эвент срабатывает (выводит в консоль)
          />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
onChange={e => this.setState({ searchData: e.target.value })}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вместо value={searchData} следует использовать

```
defaultValue={searchData}
```